# Create a set/array of NSString's to use with stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I'd like to replace certain similar words in my `NSString` with a specific string. For example:

```
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Hello" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hello" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Hey" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hey" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Hi" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hi" withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
```

This isn't very efficient, obviously, and I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution.

Is it possible to put these `NSString`'s in an array, or some kind of string set, so the resulting code would look more like:

```
stringToChange = [stringToChange stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:arrayOfStrings withString:@"Top o' de marnin ter yer"];
```

Where `arrayOfStrings` would contain `@"Hello", @"hello", @"Hey", @"hey", @"Hi", @"hi"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly put your search strings into a collection, loop over the collection, and then do a search-and-replace for each step of the loop. But that's also a loop over the string for every item in your search list.

Instead, you should use an `NSScanner`, moving through the string as matches are found. For longer source strings, you will find this *far* more efficient, in both time and space. Using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` creates a new string every time; you could of course ameliorate that by converting to an `NSMutableString` first and using `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`

Here's how to use the scanner:

```
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:source];
NSMutableString * fixedUpString = [NSMutableString string];

NSArray * searchStrings = @[/* The items you want to remove */];
NSString * replacementString = /* The new material */;

while( ![scanner isAtEnd] ){

    // Moving through the string, try each search in turn
    for( NSString * searchString in searchStrings ){

        // If there's a match, save what's been scanned up to that point
        NSString * scanned;
        if( [scanner scanUpToString:searchString intoString:&scanned] ){

            [fixedUpString appendString:scanned];
            // and add the new material
            [fixedUpString appendString:replacementString];
            // Move past the searched piece and continue
            [scanner scanString:searchString intoString:NULL];
        }
    }
}
```

`fixedUpString` now contains all the stuff from the original string, with your target phrases replaced.